# Gtx 780 on ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, graphics

I'm trying to get a gtx 780 to work on my ubuntu 18.04 installation.
Specifically it's this model from asus https://www.asus.com/Graphics-Cards/GTX780DC23GD5/

At first I had the system running on the integrated intel gpu.
Then I installed the nvidia proprietary drivers (newest ones, nvidia-driver-440) and put in the graphics card. When I booted, after the the kubuntu logo I see a black screen with a blinking underscore.
Trying different drivers gets me the same result, the older drivers (340,390) giving me additional blue tears on the screen and no option to switch to tty2 with Ctrl-Alt-F2.
Created /etc/modeprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf
containing

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
```

No change.
Tried adding nomodeset in grub, no change.

After changing a line in /etc/default/grub from

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia-drm.modeset=1"
```

I got X running again but it doesn't use the driver and the resolution is 640x480.

Currently I'm having the nvidia-driver-418 installed.
If I install older drivers (390 for example) I get the black screen with blinking underscore and blue tears, installing newer drivers get X to run but it doesn't load the drivers.

I've searched quite a lot and I'm a bit lost. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: It is disabled. My system doesn't even support it apparently.